How do I only replace certain characters in multiple files?
I have a project to replace certain characters in hundreds of files using Python (my language of choice but it could be anything really). I want to be able to run this script and have the modified files sent to a new location. Trying to fully automate this process as I cannot expect to do this manually. Bonus points if the script can automatically execute whenever I drag and drop files into a folder (not sure on the feasibility of this, I'm very ignorant in this area).
The goal is to modify the "u" characters to the right of the numbered values (see second column below; ex. "114.30u") as "o". However, if the line is proceeded by a "  o" or "  u", the character should be "s" (see first column below). The files can be 10-100 lines depending on how the files are created. However, they all adhere to the same line-format below, while only adjusting values and shifting code blocks around (BO, AK, SI, etc.).
Example text in .nc1 file (header not shown):
BO
  o   114.30u    78.61  11.11   0.00
  o  1212.85u    78.61  11.11   0.00
  o   381.00u    78.61  11.11   0.00
SI
  h   63.50u   63.50  0.00  25rX.0000005-B12
AK
  o     0.00u   100.84   0.00
  o  1327.15u   100.84   0.00
  o  1327.15u     0.00   0.00
  o     0.00u     0.00   0.00
  o     0.00u   100.84   0.00
AK
  u  1327.15u   100.84   0.00
  u     0.00u   100.84   0.00
  u     0.00u     0.00   0.00
  u  1327.15u     0.00   0.00
  u  1327.15u   100.84   0.00
PU
  v   133.35u   136.91  0.00
  v   133.35u    60.71  0.00
EN

I made my best attempt at a prototype with my limited knowledge and the internet, but it is not correct:
initialCode = []

with open ("filepath\\file.nc1", "r") as reader:
    for line in reader.readlines():
        initialCode.append(line)

WebHoles = []
NewCode = []

for chars in initialCode:
    whatWeNeed = chars.replace("u","o")
    WebHoles.append(whatWeNeed)

for chars in WebHoles:
    whatWeNeed = chars.replace("\n","")
    NewCode.append(whatWeNeed)

with open ("filepath\\file [OPTIMIZED].nc1", "w") as writer:
    for i in NewCode:
        writer.write(i)
        writer.write("\n")

I am having trouble writing the conditional formatting for modifying only the second column, so it's not included. Also, my script only searches for one named file, and not a file directory to sift through hundreds of files in one execution, so that is another missing element on my part.
Here is the expected result from the original example above (header not shown):
BO
  o   114.30s    78.61  11.11   0.00
  o  1212.85s    78.61  11.11   0.00
  o   381.00s    78.61  11.11   0.00
SI
  h   63.50o   63.50  0.00  25rX.0000001-B12
AK
  o     0.00s   100.84   0.00
  o  1327.15s   100.84   0.00
  o  1327.15s     0.00   0.00
  o     0.00s     0.00   0.00
  o     0.00s   100.84   0.00
AK
  u  1327.15s   100.84   0.00
  u     0.00s   100.84   0.00
  u     0.00s     0.00   0.00
  u  1327.15s     0.00   0.00
  u  1327.15s   100.84   0.00
PU
  v   133.35o   136.91  0.00
  v   133.35o    60.71  0.00
EN

While I'd like the original format to remain intact, I believe as long as the items in each line have spaces between them, and they remain on their respective lines, extra spaces can be added or removed and they won't impact the function of the files.
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. I apologize I haven't made much headway on this, as I'm not really a programmer.

There's no need for the first for loop. Just do initlalCode = reader.readlines()

Why do you remove all the newlines, then add them back when writing the file? Why not just write the lines as they are?

Your code makes no attempt to restrict the replacement to the letter after the number. And it doesn't check whether the line begins with u or o. You don't seem to be making any real attempt to implement the conditions you really want. You've written a stub of code and expect us to do the real work for you.,

Hint: Use a regular expression to match the letter after a number. And use an if statement to check the first part of the line.

You can use writer.writelines(newCode) instead of a for loop.
